# How to solve maximum-Firstminimum in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
static int maxDifference(int[] a) {
    int minimum, diff = -1;
    if(a.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    minimum = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        diff = Math.max(diff, a[i] - minimum);
        minimum = Math.min(minimum, a[i]);
    }
    return diff;
```

While i was searching code for max-Firstmin found this code. Please explain how this code works for the input `int[a]={20,10,65,95,110,200,60,700,5}` it returns 700-10 not 700-5.How?

Comment: change the order of your two statements

Comment: is this java or c++?

Comment: you understood the problem in max-min but it is maximum-First_minimum , read about the problem statement carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm (as @Pavneet wrote) computes maximum from differences between value and minimum from all **previous** values - not all values. So in your example:

```
 int[a]={20,10,65,95,110,200,60,700,5}
 i=0, result = 0 (minimum from all previous values = 20 and value = 20) 
 i=1 result = 0 (minimum = 20, value = 10)
 ...
 i=7, result = 700 -10 (minium = 10, value = 700)
 i=8, result = -5 (miniumum= 10, value = 5)

 max(0,0..,700-10,-5) = 700-10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Below code, which will give you expected answer.

```
static int maxDifference(int[] a)
{
   int minimum, diff , maximum = -1;
   if(a.length == 0) {
   return -1;
   }
   minimum = a[0];
   maximum = a[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) 
   {
      minimum = Math.min(minimum, a[i]);
      maximum = Math.max(maximum , a[i]);
   }
   diff = maximum - minimum;
   return diff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will work.

```
static int maxDifference(int[] a) {
    int min = a[0];
    int max = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
       if(min > a[i])
           min = a[i];
       if(max < a[i])
           max = a[i];
    }
    return ( max - min );
}
```